# Randomize Header Background On Page Refresh

Tags: php, html, css, background-image

I have looked through a couple of threads, with no luck to this problem. I'm just trying to have different images appear on a new page load for the homepage only. The CSS element I'm trying to change is

`.header_container`

The html tag is this:

`<header id="masthead" class="site-header header_container" role="banner">`

I have three images that I would like to rotate in. I have tried to call a php file that calls the images from /images/ and that didn't work.

Here is the site ---> http://www.l4sb.com

Thanks for any help you might have.

Comment: what ever cms that is, there will be a plugin to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store available image paths in PHP array like:

```
$aBgImages = array('img01.jpg','img02.jpg');
```

Then add a a `<script>` tag with something like:

```
var myElem = document.getElementById['header'];

myElem.style.backgroundImage="url('<?php echo array_rand($aBgImages) ?>')";
```

The above is not tested, just a rough example.

Comment: Yeah, I have been playing around with it and made the php array. What was wrong, was that another CSS background was overriding it. I got it to work. Thanks.